# Linq to Entities - Add a Second Join with Multiple ON conditions

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I currently can do a successful join on two tables like this:

```
            var query = db.DepoAccounts
           .Join(db.DepoAccountDetails,
                 t1 => new { t1.INTEG_REF_NO, t1.BASE_DATE },
                 t2 => new { t2.INTEG_REF_NO, t2.BASE_DATE },
                 (t1, t2) => new DataCustomerAccountGDWHModel
                 {
                     BranchNumber = t1.BR_NO,
                     BookedBalance = t2.DP_FACE_BAL_VAL_ADJ,
                 }
           );
```

I can join on a third table like this, in order to get AccountName:

```
var query = db.DepoAccounts
            .Join(db.DepoAccountDetails,
                    t1 => new { t1.INTEG_REF_NO, t1.BASE_DATE },
                    t2 => new { t2.INTEG_REF_NO, t2.BASE_DATE },
                    (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
            .Join(db.AccountCodes,
                    j1 => j1.t2.DP_ACT_CD,
                    j2 => j2.ACT_CD,
                    (j1, j2) => new DataCustomerAccountGDWHModel
                    {
                        BranchNumber = j1.t1.BR_NO,
                        BookedBalance = j1.t2.DP_FACE_BAL_VAL_ADJ,                
                        AccountName = j2.ACT_NAME
                    }
            );
```

Now I want to add two more join conditions to what I just added, and I do this:

```
var query = db.DepoAccounts
             .Join(db.DepoAccountDetails,
                     t1 => new { t1.INTEG_REF_NO, t1.BASE_DATE },
                     t2 => new { t2.INTEG_REF_NO, t2.BASE_DATE },
                     (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
             .Join(db.AccountCodes,
                     j1 => new { j1.t2.DP_ACT_CD, j1.t2.BASE_DATE, j1.t2.BR_NO },
                     j2 => new { j2.ACT_CD, j2.BASE_DATE, j2.BR_NO },
                     (j1, j2) => new DataCustomerAccountGDWHModel
                     {
                        BranchNumber = j1.t1.BR_NO,
                        BookedBalance = j1.t2.DP_FACE_BAL_VAL_ADJ,                
                        AccountName = j2.ACT_NAME
                     }
             )
```

However, this gives me the following compile error: The type arguments for method 
'Queryable.Join (IQueryable). etc etc CANNOT BE INFERRED FROM THE USAGE.

Do I just have a syntax problem?

Comment: Your second join is using anonymous types with implied default property names, so you are attempting to compare objects of two different types: `new { DP_ACT_CD, BASE_DATE, BR_NO }` to `new { ACT_CD, BASE_DATE, BR_NO }`. These are not comparable. Add an explicit property name to the first one: `new { ACT_CD = j1.t2.DP_ACT_CD,`... The key to that error is always types (and to many C# issues).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.So, should I edit my question and indicate fix, and the accept it?

Comment: Personally I would delete the question :) You would have to add your own answer to accept it, but since you didn't find it yourself...

Comment: If you have a new question, the best way to address it is to ask a new question, not ETA the existing one.

Comment: Thanks, my friend. I am doing that now.